# CSS Aligning contact form columns

Tags: html, css, contact-form

Still new to CSS in general, I trying to align a second contact form column with the first one (maps).

I've tried floating the first to the left and the second to the right, however the second column will not line up side by side with the first column.

Using position: absolute on the second column (contact form) works but it's not responsive so I am looking for another way to do this so it's responsive.

**How can I align the contact form with the maps and have it still be responsive?**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6zyffx4/

Example:

[image]

CSS:

```
Contact form:

.page-node-28 section.block-system {
float: right;
width: 40%;

/*position: absolute;*/
/*right: 100px;*/
/*top: 110px;*/
/*float:right;*/
/*width: 40%;*/
}


Google maps:

.page-node-28 .block-google-maps {
width: 40%;
min-height: 500px;
float:left;
}
```

HTML:

Column1 (maps)

```
<section id="block-block-2" class="block block-block">
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
<ul class="contextual-links">
    <li class="block-configure first last">
        <a href="...">Configure block</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="block-google-maps">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/...">
    </iframe>
</div> 
</section> <!-- /.block -->
```

Column 2 (contact form)

```
<section id="block-system-main" class="block block-system clearfix">
<div id="node-28" class="node node-webform">
    <div class="submitted">
    <div class="content">
        <form class="webform-client-form" method="post">
            ...
        </form>
</section>
<!-- /.block -->
```

Update:
[image]

Comment: couldn't use a table with columns and rows? You should be able to just do it with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

this is the css i would use followed by media queries for responsiveness

```
.block-google-maps {
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
 }

.webform-client-form {
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/algib/pen/qdMZaz

Comment: This just moved it to the left under maps, see the update image in the question.

Comment: i didnt check the codepen but the way HTML is written, section n div by default `display: block;` so if you add `display: inline-block;` in css in answer, may b you achieve it, definining just float and width wont do any good

Comment: Just tried this—added the `display: inline-block;` to both and tried to add it to just the contact form block, and it still does not move the contact form to the right aligning with the maps. It still stays under the maps block.

Comment: @peter_jackson have a look at this fiddle - your code is v messy, i cleaned it up a bit https://jsfiddle.net/e2jsa11t/1/

Comment: @RachelGallen Well it's copy and paste from Drupal. Tried your changes am getting the same thing, it's being aligned under maps like in the update example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% accurate but will give you clear idea how you can achieve it

HTML

```
<section id="block-block-2" class="block block-block">
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
<ul class="contextual-links">
    <li class="block-configure first last">
        <a href="...">Configure block</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="block-google-maps">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/...">
    </iframe>
</div> 
</section> <!-- /.block -->

<section id="block-system-main" class="block block-system clearfix">
<div id="node-28" class="node node-webform">
    <div class="submitted">
    <div class="content">
        <form class="webform-client-form" method="post">
            ...
        </form>
</section>
<!-- /.block -->
```

CSS

```
#block-block-4 {
    width: 100%;
}

.block-google-maps {
    float:left;
    width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.block-google-maps iframe {
    width: 400px;

}
.node-webform{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6zyffx4/21/)

And as far responsive, you have to use media queries.

Comment: This just aligned the contact form to the left under the maps. I've posted a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6zyffx4/ I am trying to get them side by side (maps on the left and form on the right aligned with each other)

Comment: Ok, tired this again, and still it puts it under the maps block as shown in the 'update' example in the question.

Comment: updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x6zyffx4/21/, i didnt change the HTML but you have to adjust the css classes like in updated fiddle i use `.block-google-maps` but in your original fiddle `.page-node-28 .block-google-maps` i dont have page-node-28 define in HTML so cant use it in fiddle

Comment: Tried your latest code with the same names without using `page-node-28` etc, and the contact form is still stacking under the maps block like in the update picture.  I am guessing the Drupal 7 code is overriding the changes? Only way I've been able to position it is by using `position: absolute`.

Comment: It's on my local machine.  Just don't understand why it's not working and yet using `postiion:absolute` works and `right: 100px`.

Comment: this is the html form: http://pastebin.com/VacWPXWM, the CSS is on the fiddle, haven't changed it

Comment: i also need the css you are using in your contact page, coz may be your css is nested so the one i m wirting is not taking effecting this is the updated fiddle, paste your css update it n paste link here https://jsfiddle.net/x6zyffx4/23/

Comment: Here it is am using position absolute on the contact form on this: https://jsfiddle.net/x6zyffx4/24/

Comment: tell me this is right https://jsfiddle.net/x6zyffx4/25/ :D and always use hard refresh to update the page so change take effects, sometime browser pick css from cache n the changes are right but still show old css

Answer (score 0):

I added the following rules to your css on the jsfiddle:

```
/* I added the following three rules to your css on the jsfiddle */
.myContainerDiv {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 950px;
}
.myContainerMapDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.myContainerFormDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* I added the above rules */
```

Next, I broke your code up into one containing div (aka, myContainerDiv) and two child divs respectively named: myContainerMapDiv that contains the google map stuff, and myContainerFormDiv that contains the form elements stuff.

The css I added pushed both child divs to the left.
Then, the parent sets the vertical alignment so that they both have relative  positioning to the top of the parent.

Finally, I also added clipping to my css, to show that some of the other elements contain sizing values that can affect your ability to have successful results. For instance, the map's iframe has a width of 600px you can't get away from, and the textarea also gets clipped based on the widths that I gave those divs.

Hope it sheds some light!